# How to truncate multiline text with inline button at the end

Tags: html, css

[image: Problem]

I have a problem from the picture, so multiline text with an inline button at the end, text is truncated on predetermined line, before Read more button.

Case 1: I have a solution if shown text is only one line:

```css
.inside-box {
    width: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 10px;
}

.text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="inside-box">
    <span className="text">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
        has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
        printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </span>
    <button class="btn-2">Read more</button>
</span>
```

Case 2: is using -webkit-line-clamp but then button is not in the same line.

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
}

.number-of-lines-02 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="number-of-lines-02">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
        has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
        printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </span>
    <button>Read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use an `a href` inside the span instead of a `button` ?

Comment: There is no easy solution for this. You would basically need your button to behave like it had `float: right`, but aligned at the bottom of the container, instead of the top - a feature, which does not exist. You could try and emulate something similar perhaps, using `shape-outside` - provided you can create an appropriate shape.

Answer (score 1):

I would use some Javascript to achieve this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.excerpt').forEach(e => {
  if (e.innerHTML.length <= 100) return
  e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.substring(0,100) + '...'
  e.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ' <button>Read more</button>')
})
```

```css
.excerpt {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="excerpt">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
</p>

<p class="excerpt">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
</p>

<p class="excerpt">
  Cras volutpat velit non mi sagittis condimentum. Cras tempor aliquet turpis sed pretium. Nunc aliquet sodales turpis quis ultrices. Duis auctor accumsan enim, quis maximus ex malesuada a. Donec a felis ut erat tempus euismod non vel neque. Proin lectus massa, sagittis at imperdiet nec, consequat ut neque. Sed vel placerat neque, vel varius urna. Vivamus interdum euismod urna a accumsan. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
```